# Solving base e equation $e^x - e^{-x} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, exponentiation, transcendental-equations

So I ran into some confusion while doing this problem, and I won't bore you with the details, but it comes down to trying to solve $e^x - e^{-x} = 0$.

I know to solve it, we can rewrite it as $e^x - \frac{1}{e^x} = 0$ and then get LCD so form $\frac{e^{2x} - 1}{e^x} = 0$ and then rewrite it as $e^{2x} = 1$, take the natural logarithm of both sides and it becomes $2x = \log(1)$ or when $x = 0$ (if anything up there is wrong, please tell me)

My problem is when I try to do an alternative. Starting with $e^x - e^{-x} = 0$, I try to add to both sides to get $e^x = e^{-x}$, and then take the natural logarithm of both sides to get $x = -x$, which is not a true statement. Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you should use MathJax. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a summary. In your final paragraph, you say $x=-x$ is not a true statement. But if $x=0$, it *is* true.

Comment: Your fist approach leads to $2x=\ln{1}=0$ then $x=0$. Your second approach leads to $x=-x$ then $x=0$

Comment: Not to be a snob about it, but in mathematics, $\log x$ refers to the natural logarithm, and the common logarithm is then $\log_{10} x$.

Comment: @James47: Any mathematician would understand $\ln(x)$ to be the natural logarithm of $x$. On the other hand, using $\log(x)$ can sometimes introduce ambiguity.

Comment: @DeathkampDrone That's why I qualified it with "not to be a snob about it." Because some people understand what it means yet act like it's meaningless gibberish.

Comment: In fact, $e^x-e^{-x}$ is precisely $2\sinh x$. So you are really solving $\sinh x = 0$. The solutions are the complex numbers $i\pi k$ for integral $k$; the only real-valued solution among these, if that's what you need, is $0$.

Comment: And [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2Sinh](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2Sinh) gives a plot (as a function of a real variable), and other info, on $2 \sinh$.

Comment: Thanks for the mathjax. I didn't know how to edit, but thanks James47 for the edits. I appreciate it. Looks a lot better :).       I actually didn't know it was equal to 2sinhx. Thanks for that. Might come in handy later :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If $$x = -x$$

Then we can say that  $$x = 0$$

Because

$$ x + x = -x + x $$

$$ 2x = 0 $$

$$ x = 0 $$

Answer (score 18):

You are solving for $x$ when $e^x=e^{-x}$. It is not the case for all $x$ that  $e^x=e^{-x}$; therefore, the statement $x=-x$ will not be true for all $x$, just the $x$ you are solving for.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Both are correct. $x=-x\Leftrightarrow 2x=0\Leftrightarrow x=0$.

Comment: Simple and to the point. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

When you take logs of both sides, you don't get $x=-x$. You get $x = -x +2\pi ik$ for integral $k$. This means $2x = 2\pi ik$, so $x = \pi ik$.

The only real-valued solution, then, is $x=0$ (by taking $k=0$).

Comment: I think the phrasing of the question makes it clear that the OP is asking from the perspective of real-valued functions only.  This is swatting a fly with a trebuchet.

Comment: Yeah mweiss is right. I didn't ask for that because I didn't know such a thing existed. Thanks for the extra info though. It's to be exposed to different things.

Comment: @mweiss, "swatting a fly with a trebuchet" I need to remember this phrase for use in the future.

Answer (score 4):

> and then take the natural logarithm of both sides to get $x=−x$, which is not a true statement

And right there is your mistake.

$x=-x $    **is** a true statement...  but only for $x=0$.
Just add $x$ to both sides.

Comment: I forgot taking the natural log of a negative is a no-no. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

Start off with $$e^x-e^{-x}=0$$
Add $e^{-x}$ to both sides of the equation.
The equation becomes $$e^x=e^{-x}$$
Take the natural logarithm of both sides.
$$\ln(e^x)=\ln(e^{-x})$$
$$x=-x$$
$$x=0$$