# Solve algebraically: $e^x =e^{-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, transcendental-equations

AP calc final tomorrow, this was part of my review, I have no idea how to solve it. I know the answer but not how to get the answer, which is really important.

Comment: Draw the graphs of $y=e^x$ and $y=e^{-x}$ and look for where they cross.

Comment: $\exp$ is injective so $x = -x$. What can you conclude?

Comment: natural log of both sides, also.

Comment: Might become more obvious if you look at it as $e^x=\cfrac{1}{e^x}\,$.

Comment: You might be able to find similar questions from the past [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24e%5Ex%20%3De%5E%7B-x%7D%24&p=1). For example, this related question was among the first hits: [Solving base e equation $e^x - e^{-x} = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/867329)

Comment: May be prudent to review rules for manipulating exponents.
e.g.
$$e^x = e^{-x}$$
$$e^x = e^{-1\cdot x}$$
$$e^x = (e^{x})^{-1}$$
From here, it becomes a no brainer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $t=e^x$. Then $e^{-x}=1/e^x=1/t$, so you have
$$t=\frac1t$$
which means 
$$t^2=1.$$
This means $t=\pm1$. So it only remains all possibilities for $x$ such that 
$$e^x=1 \quad\text{or}\qquad e^x=-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

hint: multiply by $e^x$ on both sides. Then you get a constant on one side. Can you solve it now?

Comment: This should be a comment, in my opinion.

Comment: @TheCount Sorry for that, but I see people giving hints as answers all the time. I will try to comment next time. Thank you!

Comment: Well it is just my opinion. No big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=iy$. Then, $\cos(y)+i\sin(y)=\cos(y)-i\sin(y)$.

$\sin(y)=0$.

$y=n\pi, n=0,\pm1,\pm2, ...$

$x=i(n\pi)$

$x=0$ is only one of the many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A more general question: for which $z \in \mathbb C$ is $e^z=e^{-z}$ ?

Answer: first recall that the complex solutions of the equation $e^w=1$ are given by

$$w=2 k \pi i, \quad k \in \mathbb Z.$$

Hence $e^z=e^{-z}$ iff $e^{2z}=1$ iff $z= k \pi i$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$.

For real $z$ it follows:

$e^z=e^{-z}$ iff $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^x = e^{-x}$$

$$\ln(e^x) = \ln(e^{-x})$$

$$x = -x$$

$$x=0$$

Come on man.